# shell script that logs into bitbucket and pulls changes

Tags: git, bash, shell, bitbucket

I am trying to login into bitbucket and pull changes from server to a remote folder for example.
Problem is that bitbucket username i have consists from `@` and its making a conflict when i am trying to write a `.sh` script to login and pull.
My code looks like :

```
#!/bin/bash
git pull "https://<username@email.com>:<password>@bitbucket.org/"
```

Branch I am trying to pull from is `origin/master`.

Comment: Have you ever done this from the command line? Or just from UIs/etc.? Have you tried URL escaping the email address?

Comment: from command line it is working by default, if i type `git pull` then window gets prompted and asks me for username/passwords. I was just trying to automatize it a bit and and run in multiple folders.

Comment: Does bitbucket support ssh keys? If so, just save your public key there, and you won't be prompted for username anymore.

Comment: bitbacket allows you access to your repos via ssh with urls like this git@bitbucket.org:<your_login>/<repo_name>.git
Just add into your account a ssh key generated on your pc.

Comment: So no, you haven't done *this* from the command line.

Comment: So `git pull https://user@bitbucket.org/repo/repo.git` is working. how do i specify specific branch in this command? also is it possible to add a password as well.

Comment: as say docs `git pull [options] [<repository> [<refspec>...]]`, so just add after url a branch that you need